# PDF modified date with xelatex

Tags: xetex

Suppose I have the following document foo.tex (MWE below). If I do `$ latexmk -xelatex foo.tex` I get a PDF with a created date which makes sense. For one I did this morning, it's 'Thu 26 Nov 2020 11:31:47 UTC'. It has a modified date of 'Wed 31 Dec 1969 23:59:59 UTC'; presumably, this is something to do with 'Unix time': https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time. This doesn't happen with `$ latexmk -pdf foo.tex`; modified = created, which makes sense to me.

Why does this happen? Do I need to fix it, and can I?

I am using Ubuntu 20.10 and TexLive 2020. I see the modified date when I open the PDF with Evince, but not with Okular.

As noted in the comments, this isn't to do with latexmk. It happens with `$ xelatex foo.tex` and `$ pdflatex foo.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: by default xelatex doesn't add  a /ModDate entry to the info dictionary. Your pdf viewer seems to fill it with a default date (adobe reader shows an empty field)

Comment: Note that (in accordance with Ulrikes comment) this is not related to `latexmk`, just running `xelatex` produces this behavior.

Comment: Note that `latexmk -pdf` is just `pdflatex`, so I'm not sure what you are comparing here. As mentioned, it might be an idea to tell which tool you've used to show that date.

Comment: It seems to me that @UlrikeFischer gave the answer, i.e., xelatex doesn't add a modified date, but pdflatex does. And then it's a question of how different viewers deal with that.